# Cant hide multiple NSButtons in one Action?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ibaction, nsbutton

I'd like to set "TheButton" to **disabled**, and "TheLastButton" to **not hidden**. TheButton will disable, but TheLastButton just stays hidden. 
Here's the code:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{

    NSButton *TheButton = sender;
    [TheButton setEnabled: NO];

    [_spinner setHidden:NO];
    [_spinner setIndeterminate:YES];
    [_spinner setUsesThreadedAnimation:YES];
    [_spinner startAnimation:nil];

    NSLog(@"started");

    //1
    NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];

    //2
    task.launchPath = @"/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister";
     [task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-kill", @"-seed", @"-r", @"-f", @"-v", @"-domain local", @"-domain user", @"-domain system", nil]];

     NSLog(@"finished");

    [_spinner setHidden:YES];

    NSButton *TheLastButton = sender;
    [TheLastButton setHidden:NO];
```

Comment: are you creating the buttons programamtically ?

Comment: How do you click on a hidden button or see if it is enabled? sender, TheButton and TheLastButton are the same button.